# Transpose Data From row to column in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function myFunction() {    
var mastersheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Feeder'); //get 
data from mastersheet
var products = mastersheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues(); //getting values 
in range specified of column B
var lenght_products = products.filter(String).length; //getting amount of 
cells with content column B
var tasks = mastersheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
var lenght_tasks = tasks.filter(String).length;
var mastersheet1 = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Products-Services');
var i;
var j;
var final = []
for (i = 0; i <= lenght_tasks- 1; i++){
     for (j = 0; j <= lenght_products- 1; j++){
        final.push(tasks[i] + " - " + products[j]);}}
```

//the output is generating a list that translates to a row, I need a list that translates to a column that can be inputed in a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Read my comments:

```
function myFunction() {    
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mastersheet=ss.getSheetByName('Feeder'); 
  var products=mastersheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();//this is a two dimensional array
  var lenght_products=products.filter(String).length;//this is meant to be run on a one dimensional array
  var tasks=mastersheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();//this is a two dimensional array
  var lenght_tasks=tasks.filter(String).length;//same problem
  var mastersheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Products-Services');
  var final=[];
  for (var i=0;i<=lenght_tasks-1;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<=lenght_products-1;j++){
      final.push(tasks[i] + " - " + products[j]);//Even single columns require two parameters.  Which is another way of saying that columns are still two dimensional arrays.
    }
  }
}
```

Also take some time and learn how to post code in questions correctly and complete.  You need to provide minimum reproducible example. You should spend some time single stepping through this code and looking at the debugger carefully to see what the arrays look like.